# Can't show the figure by networkx in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, networkx

I'v drawn a graph in jupyter already, but the code that works well in jupyter can't show the figure in pycharm.
the error message is "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: isinstance(..., numbers.Number)   if cb.is_numlike(alpha):".
In jupyter:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ql9Z.png)

In pycharm:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytKkY.png)

Comment: Hi,  welcome to stackexchange,  It would be helpful if instead of posting a screenshot of the code, you actually entered it into the question.  This makes it possible for others to copy and paste exactly the code you have run to see what the issue might be.

Comment: And a deprecation warning is not usually an error, but rather a warning that in the future the code you're using will produce an error because a function will be removed.

Comment: Are you able to view other plots you make in pycharm?  I'm wondering if you're missing the `plt.show()` command.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Missing 'plt.show()' is exactly my problem. I'm sorry I don't know I should show my code due to this is my first question.  Thank you again!

Comment: No need to apologize.  I saw it was your first time.